# Zimbra: changing postfix parameters

Tags: postfix, zimbra

I would like to change mynetworks Postfix configuration parameter in Zimbra 7 on Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.

I tried the following (as zimbra user):

```
$ zmlocalconfig -e postfix_mynetworks="127.0.0.0/8 [...]"
$ postconf -e mynetworks="127.0.0.0/8 [...]"
$ zmmtactl reload
$ postfix check
$ postfix reload
```

However

```
$ postconf mynetworks
```

Shows still the old value! Anyone knows why and how to fix this? Thank you in advance

**UPDATE** After office hours I've even tried

```
# /etc/init.d/zimbra stop
# /etc/init.d/zimbra start
```

However the parameter is still not updated.

**UPDATE 2**

```
$ zmlocalconfig postfix_mynetworks
```

Shows the updated value

```
$ zmmtactl reload
Rewriting configuration files...
postfix/postfix-script: refreshing the Postfix mail system
Stopping saslauthd...done.
Starting saslauthd...done.
```

But sadly postconf mynetworks still shows the old value. Running again postconf -e sets the value and gets lost at the first postfix reload...

Comment: You can also change this in the Admin Console under Server Settings -> MTA -> MTA Trusted Networks.

Comment: @xeon, thank you, that's a good suggestion, why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem. By looking at the file /opt/zimbra/conf/zmmta.cf, I saw the following lines:

```
if VAR zimbraMtaMyNetworks
    POSTCONF mynetworks VAR zimbraMtaMyNetworks
fi
```

With zmprov I can check the current settings and change them:

```
zmprov getServer servername.mydomain | grep zimbraMtaMyNetworks
zmprov modifyServer servername.mydomain zimbraMtaMyNetworks "127.0.0.0/8 [...]"
postfix reload
```

And the problem is solved. Xeon suggested an alternative and simpler way:

> You can also change this in the Admin
>   Console under Server Settings -> MTA
>   -> MTA Trusted Networks