# Zimbra and Postfix: configuring a catch-all mailbox/domain

Tags: email, postfix, zimbra

I'm not new to Postfix, but am new to Zimbra. I've seen this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/267049/zimbra-changing-postfix-parameters) on changing Postfix parameters, and this [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-postfix-catch-all-email-accounts/) on how to configure a catch-all domain in Postfix.

What I need to find out is how to do the Postfix configuration in Zimbra (7.1.1). I checked the Zimbra Admin page and didn't see anything that would allow virtual domains (mail to *@some.domain.example). The previously mentioned "answer" listed a raft of Zimbra commands that as of yet I do not understand.

How do I put these together? And what is the best place to find out about the shell commands available for Zimbra?

**PS:** These are good answers and look like they'll do what I need. However, I should mention that the current domain setup is thus (sanitized): 1) mailhost.main.example (Domain); 2) mail.example (Domain Alias, MX is elsewhere); 3) newmail.main.example (not in zimbra, CatchAll Domain).

Do I have to add the new domain (newmail.main.example here) as a Domain Alias to make this work? I assume so.

**UPDATE:** I added the domain as an alias and used this command to work with a distribution list instead of a user:

```
zmprov modifyDistributionList list@other.domain.example zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @some.domain.example
```

Unfortunately, now I get this message when a mail comes in:

```
Your message WAS SUCCESSFULLY RELAYED to:
  <user@other.domain.example>

The message WAS NOT relayed to:
  <""@other.domain.example>: [127.0.0.1] said:
   501 5.1.3 Failed, id=12509-18, from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10025): 501 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax

This delivery report was generated by the program amavisd-new at host
other.domain.example. Our internal reference code for your message is
11304-14/3aX6PrCFUxBz
```

Checked the mailing list, and I don't see any unusual memberships.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem trying to configure an account to act as a catch all address for multiple domains and found this valuable forum entry: [catch all not working: Multi-value syntax](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Managing_Domains) 
The command

```
zmprov modifyAccount catchall@mydomain.com zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @mydomain.com
```

sets the zimbraMailCatchAllAddress attribute for account catchall@mydomain.com to value @mydomain.com. If you try to set an additional domain to that account als catchall address with the same command

```
zmprov modifyAccount catchall@mydomain.com zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @otherdomain.com
```

this value will be overwritten. Fortunately the model allows to write multiple values. The trick is to use the syntax for multi values (using the "+"symbol) instead for the other domains:

```
zmprov modifyAccount catchall@mydomain.com +zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @otherdomain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

from http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Managing_Domains#Domain_Catchall

```
su - zimbra
zmprov modifyAccount user@domain.com zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @domain.com
```

Caution: While I do run Zimbra, I have not tested this, and the source is not quite official documentation.

Comment: One thing: the desired `user@domain.com` is a distribution list, not a user account. This doesn't seem to work. Must I use a regular account?

Comment: The answer is _no_: use `modifyDistributionList` instead of `modifyAccount`.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to make this configuration change within Zimbra and not modify postfix directly.  I don't think there is any way to do that from the admin interface.  But there is a zmprov command that will set a catchall address that is pretty easy.

Create your catchall user from the admin gui

Login to your zimbra server console

Switch to the zimbra user: `sudo su - zimbra`

Issue the zmprov command to modify the user you created above: `zmprov modifyAccount catchall@yourdomain.com zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @yourdomain.com`

Comment: One thing: the desired `user@domain.com` is a distribution list, not a user account. This doesn't seem to work. Must I use a regular account?

Comment: The answer is _no_: use `modifyDistributionList` instead of `modifyAccount`.